# Catching non thrown checked exception

Tags: java, try-catch, classnotfoundexception

I have a code that invokes an external API via EJB and that API occasionally leaks an exception that is not part of the client kit, therefore resulting in `ClassNotFoundException`.

I have a try-catch block surrounding the call:

```
    try {
      thirdPartyLibrary.finalInvokeMethod();
    } catch (SomeException exception) {
      //Do something
    } catch(
    ..
    } catch (Exception exception) {
      if (exception instanceof ClassNotFoundException) {
         log.error("....");
      }
    }
```

I want to avoid using instanceof in catch, but if I add a separate catch clause for `ClassNotFoundException`, the compiler produces an error "Unreachable catch block", since `thirdPartyLibrary.finalInvokeMethod();` doesn't throw `ClassNotFoundException`.

Is there a better way to address the issue?

Comment: if the method thirdPartyLibrary.finalInvokeMethod(); is not giving a ClassNotFoundException, how can be it catching a ClassNotFoundException?? Problem can be in a different place.

Comment: I think you're confusing `ClassNotFoundException` and `NoClassDefFoundError`. And if you want to catch the latter, you can just have a catch block for it without any compile errors.

Comment: The RMI mechanism is reconstructing reply from external API via reflection and de-serialization, therefore it is throwing `ClassNotFoundException` in case it doesn't have the leaking exception in the classpath.

(hence I'm not confusing the `ClassNotFoundException` and `NoClassDefFoundError`)

Comment: @Cyrex This can happen if the `finalInvokeMethod` is declared to throw a super-class of `ClassNotFoundException` (e.g., simply `public void finalInvokeMethod() throws Exception`) but then internally actually throws an instance of `ClassNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a workaround. I've wrapped the `thirdPartyLibrary.finalInvokeMethod();` in another method that throws the checked exception. So I got a dedicated catch clause without a compiler error.

```
private someMethod() {
  try {
    callExternalAPI();
  } catch (SomeException exception) {
    //Do something
  } catch(
  ..
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException exception) {
    log.error("....");
    //Do something
  } catch (Exception exception) {
    //Do something
  }
}

private void callExternalAPI() throws ClassNotFoundException {
  thirdPartyLibrary.finalInvokeMethod();
}
```